# How to split string starting from a certain place?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

Assume I have this string `cde123abc`, I want it to split into followings:
`cde`, `123`, `abc`.

The above string is just an example, please imagine any string which contains characters and numbers.

How to do that? Regular expression??

Comment: What is split criteria and what have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

Use regular expression `match()`.

```js
alert('cde123abc'.match(/[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+/g))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you always have letters numbers letters then this should work:

```js
var str = 'cde123abc';
var result = str.split(/([0-9]+)/);
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to split to letters and numbers, the following should work:

```
while ((m = str.match (/^(\d+|[a-zA-Z]+)(.*)/)) {
    result.push (m [0]);
    str = m [1];
}
```